# matlab, randomly generate positions inside map bounds

Tags: matlab

I have the function map which takes an input of a map name string, 'Australia' ect

What i would like to do is make an array of randomly generated positions inside the map bounds and plot over the map the number of points is made by an int Points.

currently my script is

```
    function map(Name)
worldmap({Name})
land = shaperead('landareas.shp', 'UseGeoCoords', true);
geoshow(land, 'FaceColor', [0.15 0.5 0.15])
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving enough information for a full solution.

This should probably guide you in the right direction: you want to generate random points and evaluate if the fall inside or outside the polygon you have, you can easily do that with MATLAB see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html